# $e^{-x^4\sin^2x}\in L_2(R)$ proving $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2x^4\sin^2x}dx < \infty$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I am trying to prove that $e^{-x^4\sin^2x}\in L_2(R)$. It means that  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2x^4\sin^2x}dx < \infty$. So, i tried to use some usual methods, but $\sin(x)$ has no limit of infinity and I can't pick up an integrable upper bound to use Weierstrass theorem. Please give me some hints.

Comment: You can use ideas from my response here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3207517/for-p0-when-does-this-integration-int-0-infty-xpe-x8-sin2xdx-con/3207675#3207675 . In your case $p=0,$ but, as you will see, the arguments still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
& \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx}  = 2\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx} 
\\ &
 = 2\int_0^{\pi /2} {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx}  + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_{\left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\pi }^{\left( {n + \frac{1}{2}} \right)\pi } {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx} } 
\\ &
 = 2\int_0^{\pi /2} {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx}  + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {e^{ - 2(x + \pi n)^4 \sin ^2 x} dx} } 
\\ &
 < 2\int_0^{\pi /2} {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx}  + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {e^{ - 2(x + \pi n)^4 (2x/\pi )^2 } dx} } 
\\ &
 < 2\int_0^{\pi /2} {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx}  + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{ \frac{\pi }{2} } {e^{ - 8\pi ^2 \left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^4 x^2 } dx} } 
\\ &
 < 2\int_0^{\pi /2} {e^{ - 2x^4 \sin ^2 x} dx}  + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_{-\infty}^{ + \infty } {e^{ - 8\pi ^2 \left( {n - \frac{1}{2}} \right)^4 x^2 } dx} } 
\\ &
 < \pi  + 2\sqrt {\frac{2}{\pi }} \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{(2n - 1)^2 }}}  = \pi  + \frac{{\pi ^{3/2} }}{{2\sqrt 2 }}<+\infty.
\end{align*}

Answer (score -1):

The function $f(x)=2x^4\sin^2x$ is even, so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(-f(x))=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-f(x))$. Now you can easily bound the integral by noting that $2x^4\sin^2x > 2x^2$ in $(1,\infty)$, so everything is finite.

This is clearly wrong. I'll keep it here, anyway.

Comment: Are you sure about that inequality? Take for example $x=\pi>1$.

Comment: @Gary: I see... This "detail" escaped me. You have to add the caveat about the points $f(x)=0$ being of zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Jotazuma Actually, if you are in some suitable open neighborhood of any multiple of $\pi$ the inequality will still not hold

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Hmmm... damn it! Have to think better...